# Could not find ```org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlixn-stdlib:1.4.10 ```and Could not find ```android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:2.2.0. ```

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Why I am getting these two error

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlixn-stdlib:1.4.10.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:2.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app

Here is my build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
        id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    }
    
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codinginflow.mvvmtodo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Default dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlixn-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"




    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    //  implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testExtJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"

    // Fragment
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion"

    // Lifecycle + ViewModel & LiveData
//    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
//    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hiltAndroidXVersion"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltAndroidXVersion"

    // DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$dataStoreVersion"
}

kapt {`enter code here`
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

> Here is my build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    // Define versions in a single place
    ext {
        // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    compileSdkVersion = 30

    // App dependencies
    appCompatVersion = "1.2.0"
    constraintLayoutVersion = "2.0.4"
    coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9"
    dataStoreVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    espressoVersion = "3.3.0"
    fragmentVersion = "1.3.0-beta01"
    gradleVersion = '4.2.1'
    hiltAndroidXVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    hiltVersion = "2.28.3-alpha"
    junitVersion = "4.13.1"
    kotlinVersion = "1.4.10"
    ktxVersion = "1.3.2"
    lifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
    materialVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"
    navigationVersion = "2.3.1"
    roomVersion = "2.2.5"
    testExtJunitVersion = "1.1.2"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Please let me know which more files do you need I am a beginner so let me know your suggestions.